# Working with inductive loads

Tags: power, solid-state-relay, inductive

I have a 2 ton split AC that would draw about 12A current and is rated for 2260W input power at 230V. With this much information how do I choose a solid state relay? Since the rating is inductive what do I look for?

Comment: That's going to be a big, expensive solid state relay.

Comment: Your looking for a relay rated for 12A motor loads. Any thing rated for resistive or general purpose loads is going to weld the contacts (for normal relays) or blow the solid state switch.

Comment: You may want a motor relay or contactor. "Contactors" are really relays, but they are specifically designed for controlling power to AC motors. Personally I would not go solid state for this load, but if you do, pay attention to power dissipation in the relay.

Comment: Yep!... this http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/contactors/3927380/?origin=PSF_421211|fp&cm_sp=featureproducts-_-FeaturedProductsContent-_-3927380 is sort of what you need.

Comment: No tell me what do I need to check? The parameters? I just don't understand it when "inductive" loads come into picture. Everything becomes expensive and hotter. When they specify 2260W power can't a relay thats rated 20A@230V be sufficient , isn't Power = V X I = 230 X 20 =4600W, which is much higher than required? If this how its not calculated, how do I actually calculate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing special is needed. You can buy a SSR **without** zero-cross detector for rated current, let's say 25A or more. Parallel at the output you should install aditional snubber network, that is a resitor and capacitor in series. 
Zero-cross SSR isn't a good choice for inductive loads, while a circuit withoust snubber can have problems while turning off.

http://www.ebay.com/itm/24V-380V-40A-250V-SSR-40-DA-Solid-State-Relay-Module-3-32V-DC-To-AC/201414937205?_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m1851&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20131003132420%26meid%3D8b8f3c5230224c97bd155701bbab988d%26pid%3D100005%26rk%3D3%26rkt%3D6%26sd%3D381377525783

http://www.ebay.com/itm/0-1uF-100-Ohm-250V-250VAC-RC-network-contact-suppressor-triac-SCR-snubber-Qty1-/121715922545?hash=item1c56d59671

About different types of SSR and their applications:
http://www.crydom.com/en/tech/newsletters/solid%20statements%20-%20ssrs%20switching%20types.pdf

Comment: Wait, how is the SSR controlled if the zero-cross detector is removed? And you've linked me to a 40A SSR with 24-380VAC , how did you choose this?

Comment: I have just searched the ebay, it doesn't mean it is the right for you, just an example. You would need to get the datasheet and make sure is random turn on (non zero cross). Random turn on, turns on at no matter what is the actual phase voltage.

Comment: One thing I understood now is "random turn on" SSRs are used for inductive loads. So thats done. Now how do I check for the rating? Since my AC runs at 12A, can I go for a 20A random turn on SSR?

Comment: Yes, look what you get for the price, usually a SSR brick is rated 25A, 40A, 65A,.. also look if it has in built snubber, otherwise you can buy it or make it with a 0.1uF/250VAC  cap + 100 ohm/1W resistor. Also find a suitable brick for your input control voltage if it is AC or DC.

Comment: Finding a random turn on SSR is a real pain. Why is it so rare?

Answer (score 2):

A detailed answer to the SSR question follows a more complete look at what causes contractors to fail, but the short answer is that the required SSR will be rated 300A-400A and 370V. The SSR plus heat-sinking and MOV snubbers will be around 2x the cost of a reasonably good 40A contactor and the wiring and mechanical layout will required some skill to install.

An SSR is typically contemplated when a relay or contactor has failed, and it’s not always the best approach to improving the reliability of an existing machine. Reasonably good fully derated contactor (e.g. 40A contactor for a 12A FLA compressor) should last >100,000 cycles +/- 50%.
If a system has a (truly excessive) 10 cycles an hour (6 minutes between starts) that’s around 80,000 cycles a year. At that point an SSD makes sense, but to realize increased system reliability requires upgrading other components for motor starting and to run the condenser fan after compressor shut off to prevent starting into head pressure. If the 2 ton machine has run cycles that are always more than 10 minutes and usually longer, and has a 20A contactor or just an “ice cube” relay, then an upgraded electromechanical switch is probably a better next-step.

Verifying or upgrading the motor’s starting system is also appropriate.
A failing start or run capacitor will cause excessive starting current that over-stresses the power contacts.  Other causes include wiring or shutoff switch with a large voltage droop, or a weak 24v control transformer not closing the contacts rapidly during the turn on transient causing them to erode rapidly.

Good industrial control transformers are larger and cost a little more than low cost 24v 40VA control transformers, but relays snap closed quickly. If an intermediate relay bounces or any other device causes the power-on signal to flutter then the power contacts chatter closed instead of snapping closed and they erode rapidly.

Repairing a failing upstream control is preferable to immediately installing an on-delay timer set to 1 sec to de-bounce the relay drive, but diagnosing the problem requires an oscilloscope and a particular model of relay may simply bounce, so it’s more cost effective to clean up the drive signal with an on-delay until it actually fails.

The compressor motor will start most efficiently if it’s started by a starting relay that senses the voltage (or current) in the start winding along with the correct size start capacitor. Researching the correct pick-up and drop-out voltage (or current) and starting capacitor for the compressor is required.

There are a limited number of “good” choices for designing a given size motor, so a similar model from the same manufacturer is likely to use the same starting components. If service information gives the same DC resistance for the windings and the run capacitor is the same it’s very likely to use the same starting components. Some/many 3-wire electronic aftermarket start relays with adjustable pickup/dropout voltage don’t perform as expected and function as simple time-out start relays, as will most start relays that say “universal”, caveat emptor.

A simple time based start device like a PTC or a 2 wire hard start is on for the longest possible start so it’s almost always on longer than it should be which wastes energy and is hard on both the motor and the contactor.
An oversized 2-wire hard-start device is particularly punishing. So - make sure what’s needed isn’t a motor capacitor(s), a better control voltage transformer, an on-delay to clean up the control drive, a new power shut-off or power feed “whip”, a “real” motor start relay, or tightening some wiring connection (look for the one that looks like it was cooked ‘well-done’). If there isn’t a simple cause for the relay component failure, it’s simpler and cheaper to upgrade to a 40A contactor than an SSD.

An SSR for a conventional 2 ton 12A (full load) air conditioner will be turning on to spin up the compressor’s internal split phase motor and the condenser fan’s split phase motor. The SSR needs to survive the motor turn on current transient, typically between 8 and 12 times the full load current. This transient persists for only a fraction of a second, but will damage an under-sized SSR over time.

Of greater concern is the stalled motor transient that is the same stalled rotor  current for 3-5 seconds until the motor protection device snaps open. These stalled compressor events do occur for a variety of reasons, so instead of using 50% of the 144A peak current (72A) for the SSR current rating, the entire 144A rating is used. These events are more likely to occur at either low outdoor temperature due to liquid migration, or very high outdoor ambient temperature when a simple restart time control may not be long enough to get the condenser pressure down far enough to spin up an aging machine.  The SSR must also be derated for high ambient temperature, 50% for most locations, 70% in the warmest areas, so now the target device is either 288A (300A) or a 400A device.

The price of this SSR component should be very close to price of an electromagnetic contactor, but heatsinking and inductive spike clamping are needed. The heat sinking should conform to the SSR data sheet. The MOV should be chosen with guaranteed calming voltage at 30% over the peak line voltage, 1.414 x 1.3 x (line voltage).

If the air conditioner is using a variable speed compressor motor with an inverter drive, a different set of design considerations apply, and adding some inductance to limit the current inrush is required, but this is an answer, not a textbook, so only a retrofit for a conventional machine is considered. Likewise the compressor transients are assumed to be much larger than the condenser fan and any condenser fan speed controls are assumed to be benign speed controls, if a bang-bang control is used e.g. a pressure switch, then additional MOV spike control at the fan may be needed.

Comment: Hi, Oliver. This is a really difficult read. I suggest you make more paragraph breaks and maybe a section head for each logically grouped set of paragraphs.

Comment: An extremely nice and useful answer. Some people may benefit from a few more paragraph breaks to separate major points. (My brain seems to handle data-dump mode OK :-) ). I'll be saving this for future reference and may copy a link  to another site

Comment: @transistor But, well worth an encouraging upvote for the superb content ?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, it was to much work, hence my comment. The content might be great.

Comment: @Transistor I was not disagreeing with you - just suggesting that an encouraging upvote was still warranted. No? I've added some white space and corrected a few typos.  I invited Oliver to change what I'd done if he wished.

Comment: Good edit, @Russell. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Inductive loads are hard on relays during turnoff.Relays that that are specified for motors are available and have a HORSEPOWER rating as well as a voltage and current rating .When the relay states a motor horsepower rating you cant go wrong .These good relays are more expensive and are physicaly larger and have generous contact spacing and are often referred to as contactors .You can go solid state if you know what you are doing .For safety there should be a mechanical contact in series with the SSR contact .For disipation reasons there should be a contact in paralell with SSR contact.The SSR aproach has been shown to be more complicated than the simple mechanical approach .The SSR way may have to be considered if your job involves a large number of switching operations.Fortunately the manufacturers of mechanical switchgear state number of operations Vs current at inductive loads .

Comment: This still doesn't explain what I asked for. Assuming my AC is rated at 2HP , you mean to say I should look for a "contactor" rather than a relay that is rated well above 2HP? Aren't relays an exact replica of mechanical switches? If the switches can handle the "sparking" during turn off why can't the SSRs? Even if I opt for a SSR instead of contactor, what parameters am I looking for? I did try digging for a SSR that also mentions Inductive Loads or HORSEPOWER, sadly no one seems to give that rating. So how do I work with a SSR?

Comment: SSR's have several problems with motor applications... the primary one being that they almost never turn completely off.  Contactors generally remain the best way of switching motor loads, and run for usually millions of cycles.  The contacts are better than plain relays, they have arc deflectors to quench the arc on opening, and a much stronger pull-in and drop out than normal relays, again, to reduce and contain arcing.